# Self join on sparsely populated table

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, parquet, presto, amazon-athena

I have a table (well, it's parquet files if that changes things) sitting in S3 to be queried by Presto/AWS Athena.

There's a lot of crap in there, but essentially the structure is:

```
SessionId, TransactionId, SessionFailureType1, SessionFailureType2
123456   , 123-c-456    ,                     , 
999999   ,              , 1                   ,
123456   , 090-2-999    ,                     , 
999999   , 111-1-111    ,                     , 
123456   ,              ,                     , 1
```

Some sessions have no transactions, and many sessions have no failures. Each transaction and session start get a row.

This situation is a lot like having two tables in one, with the foreign key being SessionId.

I'm trying to get the transactions which failed, which I think means I need to join the table on itself and then group by `SessionId`. I've tried doing a self join to get all of the `TransactionId`s:

```
SELECT TransactionId as trid, SessionId as ssid, SessionFailureType1 as f1, SessionFailureType2 as f2 
FROM MyTable a join MyTable b on a.SessionId = b.SessionId
where b.SessionFailureType1 = 1 or b.SessionFailureType2 = 1
and a.TransactionId <> '';
```

But this is giving me a bunch of results where the transaction Ids are still unpopulated, and furthermore it seems incomplete. I feel like I'm missing a fundamental issue here; maybe what I want isn't a join after all but a... bifurcate?

Comment: If a session has multiple transactions, how do you know which failed?

Comment: Any transaction within a bad session is considered failed for this case. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to get the transactions which failed,

If you want to return all transactions for sessions where one of the failure type columns is not `null`, then use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(SessionFailureType1) over (partition by sessionid) as cnt1,
             count(SessionFailureType2) over (partition by sessionid) as cnt2
      from t
     ) t
where cnt1 > 0 or cnt2 > 0;
```

Comment: This seems to do the job of partitioning the table, but for whatever reason I can't add "where" clauses to the end of it to filter, so I'm still getting a ton of empty `TransactionId`s. Is there something different about `where` clauses in these cases?

Comment: @ap . . . The window functions need to be in a subquery.